# Bootstrap, jQuery in modal doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Im making a page where you can check a few lines in a table, and then export them.

Here is the code http://www.bootply.com/Hrll6yz0c1

Code for adding lines to modal export menu works great, but code that deletes lines inside modal doesn't work.

Code for deleting

```
$('button#delB').click(function() {
     $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

For this generated table

```
$('button#addB').click(function() {
                        var toAdd = $(this).parent().parent().find("#sub_id").html();
                        var toAdd2 = $(this).parent().parent().find("#val1").html();   
                        var toAdd3 = $(this).parent().parent().find("#val2").html(); 
                        $('#tblGrid').append("<tr><td>"+toAdd+"</td><td>"+toAdd2+"</td><td>"+toAdd3+"</td><td><button type='button' class='btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove' id='delB'></button></td></tr>"); 

 });
```

I tried deleting  outside modal with the same code and it's working.

Comment: Please include your relevant code in the question. Also, `id`s should be unique!

Comment: I suspect you're binding your event handlers to buttons that don't exist at the time of binding them. Just in case it is this, try using `on()` instead.

Comment: George, There is a link to my code, is there a problem with it?

Comment: @Deniss There is no problem with you linking to your code, as long as you include the relevant code *in the question as well*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I suspected, `delB` elements are dynamically generated. So they do not exist at the point at which you're attempting to bind the click event handler to them. `on()` is therefore more suited to what you're trying to do:

```
$(document).on('click','button#delB',function() {                      
   $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

NOTE: It's very likely `$(document)` is an unnecessary scope to call `on()` on, make it more specific depending on your context.

*As an aside: heed the advice of George, make sure your ids are all unique or you'll run into problems.*

Comment: Downvote care to explain why? I actually like downvotes, but only if I can learn something from them (although I assume this was a retaliation based on timings and thus useless to anybody).

Comment: Thank you. That works. 
You mean i should make a unique id for each button?

Comment: Well that's aside from your button, but the whole purpose of an id is that it is an identifier, you can't identifier elements from each other if they share the same id. Every single element on your page should have a unique id.

Comment: According to this answere, you don't need to give every button a id. Add a class so every button gets bind with the function. And as @DeeMac already posted, you can catch the active element with `$(this)`. To the Downvote, i also hate if someone downvotes without explain. I +1'ed this answere :)